# Substituting numbers of different lengths (re.sub) in python

Tags: python, regex, substitution

```
corpus = """In the US 555-0198 and 1-206-5705-0100 are examples fictitious numbers.
            In the UK, 044-113-496-1834 is a fictitious number.
            In Ireland, the number 353-020-917-1234 is fictitious.
            And in Australia, 061-970-654-321 is a fictitious number.
            311 is a joke."""
```

I'm new to python and working on regular expressions trying to change all the 7,11,12 and 13 digit numbers to zeros. I want it to still look like a phone number. For example changing 555-0198 to 000-0000.Is there a way to keep the 311 as is without turning to zeros? Below is what I've been able to come up with

At first I tried but it made all digits zeros

```
    for word in corpus.split():
        nums = re.sub("(\d)", "0",word)
        print(nums)
```

Then I tried but I realized doing it this way won't be correct for 11 and 13 digit numbers

```
    def sub_nums():
        for word in corpus.split():
           nums = re.sub("(\d{1,4})-+(\d{1,4})", "000-0000",word)
           print(nums)
    sub_nums()
```

Comment: 1-206-5705-0100 and 061-970-654-321 have 12 digits each. Do you want to change them as well?

Comment: Yes I want to change all the phone numbers except 311

Comment: Does that mean you want to change all as long as there is no hyphen in between, and leave the rest? Your requirement ain't clear.

Comment: Sorry! I've updated the question to be a bit more clear. I want to include the hyphens so it looks like a phone number still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex I used is:

```
r'(?<!\S)(?:(?=(-*\d-*){7}(\s|\Z))[\d-]+|(?=(-*\d-*){11}(\s|\Z))[\d-]+|(?=(-*\d-*){12}(\s|\Z))[\d-]+|(?=(-*\d-*){13}(\s|\Z))[\d-]+)'
```

There is a repeating "theme" or pattern for 7, 11, 12 and 13-digit phone numbers, so I will just explain the pattern for 7-digit phone numbers:

1. `(?!\S)` This is a *negative lookbehind* that applies to all the patterns and says that the phone number must *not* be preceded by a character that is *not* white space. This is a double negative and is *almost* equivalent to saying the phone number must be preceded by white space but allows for the phone number to be preceded by the start of string. An alternative would be the equivalent *positive lookbehind* `(?=\s|\A)`, which says that the phone number must be preceded by white space *or* the start of string. However, this is a variable length lookbehind that is not supported in the regex engine that comes with Python (but is supported with the `regex` package from the PyPi repository).
2. `(?=(-*\d-*){7}(\s|\Z))` The *lookahead* requirement for the 7-digit phone number says that next characters must consist of some combination of digits and hyphens followed by either white space or the end of string *and* the number of digits must be exactly 7.
3. `[\d-]+` This does the actual matching of the next digits and hyphens in the input.

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q5O4r7/1/)

```
import re


corpus = """In the US 555-0198 and 1-206-5705-0100 are examples fictitious numbers.
            In the UK, 044-113-496-1834 is a fictitious number.
            In Ireland, the number 353-020-917-1234 is fictitious.
            And in Australia, 061-970-654-321 is a fictitious number.
            311 is a joke."""

regex = r'(?<!\S)(?:(?=(-*\d-*){7}(\s|\Z))[\d-]+|(?=(-*\d-*){11}(\s|\Z))[\d-]+|(?=(-*\d-*){12}(\s|\Z))[\d-]+|(?=(-*\d-*){13}(\s|\Z))[\d-]+)'
new_corpus = re.sub(regex, lambda m: re.sub(r'\d', '0', m[0]), corpus)
print(new_corpus)
```

Prints:

```
In the US 000-0000 and 0-000-0000-0000 are examples fictitious numbers.
            In the UK, 000-000-000-0000 is a fictitious number.
            In Ireland, the number 000-000-000-0000 is fictitious.
            And in Australia, 000-000-000-000 is a fictitious number.
            311 is a joke.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be easier to use a pattern to first match digits separated by a hyphen and then check if the number of digits in the match is equal to either 7,11,12 or 13.

For example, match the digits separated by hyphens:

```
(?<!\S)\d{1,4}(?:-\d{1,4})+(?!\S)
```

- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind, assert what is on the left is not a non whitespace char
- `\d{1,4}` Match 1-4 digits
- `(?:-\d{1,4})+` Repeat 1+ times matching a `-` and 1-4 digits
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not a non whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pyT3c2/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/MvJ8Kk)

Example Python code using [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) and a lambda

```
import re

regex = r"(?<!\S)\d{1,4}(?:-\d{1,4})+(?!\S)"

test_str = ("In the US 555-0198 and 1-206-5705-0100 are examples fictitious numbers.\n"
            "            In the UK, 044-113-496-1834 is a fictitious number.\n"
            "            In Ireland, the number 353-020-917-1234 is fictitious.\n"
            "            And in Australia, 061-970-654-321 is a fictitious number.\n"
            "            311 is a joke.")

result = re.sub(
    regex,
    lambda x: re.sub(r'\d', '0', x.group())
    if len(x.group().replace('-', '')) in (7, 11, 12, 13) else x.group(), test_str
)

print(result)
```

Output

```
In the US 000-0000 and 0-000-0000-0000 are examples fictitious numbers.
            In the UK, 000-000-000-0000 is a fictitious number.
            In Ireland, the number 000-000-000-0000 is fictitious.
            And in Australia, 000-000-000-000 is a fictitious number.
            311 is a joke.
```